# how to get year wise and month wise documents which are having 'createdat' field

Tags: mongodb

I need to generate monthly and yearly reports. So how to get year wise and month wise documents which are having 'createdat' field.

Comment: what is the output format that you are expecting?

Comment: In a collection named "orders", I had few documents containing 6-7 fields. One of the field in those documents is "createdAt". Now by giving year, I should get all the documents of that year. In the same way, if I query by month I should get all the documents of that particular month in that particular year. - @DeendayalGarg

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the `aggregation framework`
You need to project all `createdAt` fields into `year` and `month` field as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        year: {
            $year: "$createdat"
        },
        month: {
            $month: "$createdat"
        },
        log_field: 1,
        other_field: 1,
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "year": 2016
    }
}]);
```

More details about the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/)

Answer (score 0):

I realise you might not be able to change the structure of the data you have, but if you do, this might be useful to you...

I do quite a lot of this in our projects, and have always found that the best (as in, simplest and fastest) way is to actually store that kind of info up front, separately.
So as an example, I store the full datetime field (as you do), but *then also* store the YYYYMM value in its own field, as well as the Day. These values/formats might be different depending on the kind of data, but I've had very good success with it.

(For context, I'm storing financial calculation data, anywhere up to several million records per month, per customer..... not something the aggregation framework has managed nicely)
A little sample of the BSON

```
.... 
"cd" : ISODate("2016-02-29T22:59:59.999Z"),
"cdym" : "201602",
"cdd" : "29",
....
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer and this is the answer.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
{ "$redact": { 
    "$cond": [ 
        { "$and": [ 
            { "$eq": [ { "$year": "$date" }, 2016 ] }, 
            { "$eq": [ { "$month": "$date" }, 5 ] }
        ] }, 
        "$$KEEP", 
        "$$PRUNE" 
     ] } 
}
```

])